# Python Regex to replace each character in group

Tags: python, regex

Say I have a string like so

```
txt = 'Source_Test_MyStuff_v001.0746.exr'
name = re.sub(r'\.([0-9]+)\.', '#', txt )
```

Outputs:

```
Source_Test_MyStuff_full_v001#exr
```

My goal is to find the group containing only numbers between the two periods .. and replace each number within the periods (.) with pound signs.

The desired result is this...
Outputs:

```
Source_Test_MyStuff_full_v001.####.exr
```

Other examples that could occur:

```
Source_Test_MyStuff_v001.0586006.exr >> Source_Test_MyStuff_v001.#######.exr
Source_Test_MyStuff_v001.76.exr >> Source_Test_MyStuff_v001.##.exr
```

How can i achieve this with python and regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.sub(r'(?<=\.)[0-9]+(?=\.)', lambda x: '#'*len(x.group()), txt )
```

The `(?<=\.)[0-9]+(?=\.)` regex match one or more digits only when they are enclosed with dot chars on both ends, and `lambda x: '#'*len(x.group())` replaces the matches with the same amount of `#` chars as the match length.

See a [full Python demo](https://ideone.com/YBUsmD):

```py
import re
txt = 'Source_Test_MyStuff_v001.0746.exr'
print( re.sub(r'(?<=\.)[0-9]+(?=\.)', lambda x: '#'*len(x.group()), txt ) )
# => Source_Test_MyStuff_v001.####.exr
```